# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and JS based techonology combination choice

Tags: jquery, reactjs, spring-boot, vue.js, thymeleaf

As being an about old fashioned person in Java Enterprise world, need an advice from professionals in this area, because of struggling with a question which technologies are the best to combine together to have a solution with the following pre-conditions.

- Easy reusable and customisable UI components such as data tables and e.t.c.
- Fast development without struggling with the technological complexity and knowledge lack.

Current technological stack
 - Spring Boot for backend 
 - Spring Thymeleaf for UI templating in combination with JQuery.

Possible other modern solutions which raise several questions:

- Angular JS
- Vue JS
- React JS

The following questions have been arosen:

- Does it make sense to combine one of this technologies with Spring or it is better to replace Spring Thymeleaf with it?
- Would it ease up to build the UI or the combination would complicate more and it is better to stick with Thymeleaf itself?
- Are there other solutions for Spring Thymeleaf to make the development faster?

p.s. I used to work with Apache Wicket where life was way easier to build up customisable and reusable UI, several community JQuery based solutions already existing, but for Thymeleaf seams nothing is up yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your questions, as usual, it is always up to you and your deadlines. But for general ideas i can state the following:

- **Reuseable/Customisable UI**: With **Thymeleaf** you can have the option of **Fragments** which can be considered as reusable UI components. If you can design your **fragments** and **templates** with good layout ideas you can use many of the site assets as reusable components. Data tables and such components are nowadays can be easily found in JS libraries, which most of them are well tested and maintained, so you can drop any of those JS libs in your project and use them as a client-side option, which we are doing this most of the time in Thymeleaf projects we are working in (JS usage in Thymeleaf can be bothersome at first but after a few hours it is easy to work with).
- **Fast Dev:** If you are mostly an old fashioned **JAVA EE** guy like me than it is better to stick with **Spring-Boot and Thymeleaf+jQuery** (or any other supporting JS lib). Thymeleaf templating is simple, fragments come in handy, inline scripting, i18n and preprocessing are the most important things to note.Spring-Boot is very easy and no more hassle for configuration and works with Thymeleaf consistently. If you later on decide to change your project into an API then Spring also gives you the power to quickly transform your project just by refactoring your Controller methods.

Angular/React/Vue and Questions:

- These new technologies are the goto choices of View/UI nowadays because of its ease of development, modularity and adaptability. If you are willing to learn something new and if you have time then you can try one of these. I am personally into Vue.JS and i am impressed by its ease of use, modularity and flexibility and speed of development. Components and reuse is the soul of Vue.JS and if reuseablity is your primary target than you can give it a try.
- For thymeleaf ready-to-use components are the JS libs for many common tasks such as datatables, date/time management, data formatting and so on. If you know how to use JS than just add the desired JS lib to your project and use it with Thymeleaf inline JavaScript option.

As a final word;

- If you have time, want to learn new/emerging stuff, doesnt care about learning curve, make yourself comfortable with the current development stack, get your hands on a Spring-Boot REST API Backend + Vue/React/Angular UI Frontend Project i would definitely go with Vue.JS (or React/Angular if you like).
- Otherwise if you dont have time, want to be fast, want to built something rapidly and deliver the product in confidence, want to utilize the existing knowledge than i would go with the Thymeleaf option.